# transfering erc20, how is approved called from metamask

Tags: solidity, erc-20, metamask

we have a game that requires the user to transfer an ERC20 from a browser to a contract address, in unit tests approve() needs to be called from user side to enable an erc20 transfer to an address, How should this work in broweser connected to metamask?
will the frontend call approve() first and then transfer() so its two transactions?
Is there a way to detect if the receiver address already has access/approved for transfer from smart contract or solidity side so we can just put the approve() in a condition and not call approve() everytime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with checking the `allowance` for your spender by the owner.

```
function allowance(address owner, address spender) public returns uint256;
```

If the allowance is below your requirement, you'll need to first perform a `approve` transaction. And then do the `transferFrom`. If you do this as two separate transactions, it'll open up the MetaMask twice and the users will have to authorise 2 transactions separately.

We could have used multi-call contract to combine these calls inside a single transaction but most `approve` function implementations works based on `msg.sender`.

ERC-777 tries to fix this by requiring a single transaction to effectively perform the equivalent of `approve` and `transferFrom`. You can check out more about ERC-777 [here](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-777).